# How to fetch chargebee associative array response in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I am trying to fetch customer detail from chargebee using its api key, the response is in associative array. I tried to fetch values using following codes
**$all** contains response

```
foreach($all as $entry){
    $customer[] = $entry->customer();
         $card = $entry->card();
}
```

print_r($customer);

```
//try 1
    foreach($customer as $value){
      print_r($value->allowed:protected]);
    } 

//try 2
    foreach($customer as $key->$value){
          print_r($value->allowed:protected]);
        }
```

My array is in following manner

```
Array
(
    [0] => ChargeBee_Customer Object
        (
            [allowed:protected] => Array(
                    [0] => id
                    [1] => firstName
                    [2] => lastName
                    [3] => email
                    [4] => phone
                    [5] => company
             )
             [_values:protected] => Array
                ( [first_name] => ashutosh
                    [email] => ashutosheve@gmail.com)
             [_data:protected] => Array
               (
                    [firstName] => ashutosh
                    [email] => ashutosheve@gmail.com
                    [autoCollection] => on
                    [netTermDays] => 0
               )
          )}
```

It keeps throwing error

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ',' or ')'
```

How to get values from such array Please Help.

Comment: What line is the error on:  Your PHP code isn't executing...

Comment: print_r($value->allowed:protected]); gives above parse error

Comment: You have an object with protected properties.  You need a `ChargeBee_Customer` class with a get method to get them.

Comment: There's an extra "]" in there.

Comment: You can't access `:protected` properties directly using `->` syntax. You have to use the class's methods to get that information.

Comment: See the documentation at https://apidocs.chargebee.com/docs/api/customers. It looks like the `allowed` property is not exposed, it's just for internal use of the class. Why do you think you need to access this?

Comment: yes, @Barmar  How to use class's method?

Comment: There is no method for this. Why do you think you need to access the `allowed` property?

Comment: using same php example I am getting above results @Barmar

Comment: Do you understand the difference between public, private, and protected properties in PHP objects?

Comment: Private and protected properties can't be accessed directly from outside the class. But `print_r()` will still show them, it adds `:private` and `:protected` after the name to tell you that they're special.

Comment: yes, Public is globally accesible, protected and private have limitation. So Basically you are saying it's not possible to get values from such array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chargebee php library has simple ways to access each resource attributes.

You can access the attributes of the customer as shown below:

```
    $customer = $all->customer();
    print($customer->id);
    print($customer->firstName);
```

Similarly you can access other resource attributes.

You can also fetch the entire customer details as json string:

```
    $json = $customer->toJson();
    print($json);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the properties you want to get have protected access you can't do it directly. However, there are 2 ways in PHP to do that.

One is to cast the object to an array or the second one is to use [ReflectionClass](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php)

```
$reflect = new ReflectionClass('ChargeBee_Customer'); // create reflection class
$p = $reflect->getProperty('allowed'); // get protected property allowed

$p->setAccessible(true); // set it accessible

foreach ($customer as $value){
      var_dump($p->getValue($value)); //get property value on the object using reflection
}
```